# Javascript scope issue with jquery post and promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build an array from the responses of a jquery post. I have the following code:

```
categories_names = [];
$(categories).each(function(index, category_id) {
    $.post('/modules/blog/add_post_categories', {post_id:result.result, category_id:$(category_id).val()},
    function(result)
    {
        categories_names.push = result;
    });
}).promise().done(function() {
    var final_cats = categories_names.join("");
    console.info(final_cats);
});
```

The post request inserts the category id into a table and returns the name of that category formatted like `<li>Category Name here</li>` so that once the array is built and all categories selected (by checkbox in the form previous to this) are entered into the database, the array can be joined and inserted as html to the final view. At the moment the code is just printing it out in the console as you can see but as you've probably guessed, it returns `(an empty string)`

I know this is most likely a scope issue since that's the area of javascript that still totally baffles me, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on it.

Comment: Is the post happening asynchronously?

Comment: Are you sure the `post` is actually returning anything? Can you see it in the developer tools?

Comment: @MikeChristensen - I assumed not... but that would explain it... should I change the `post` to `$.ajax` so I can control that?

Comment: @MattBurland - yes... it's definitely returning the `<li>`

Comment: @dystroy - categories is the checkbox object from the form.. it is definitely cycling through it and adding the to the database correctly and returning the expected `<li>` value, just can't seem to collect them in the array

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns - Yea I'd set breakpoints (or console.log) on `categories_names.push` and `categories_names.join("")` to see which happens first..

Comment: Your `.promise().done(...)` isn't doing what you think it is. It's simply resolving instantly because there are no animations on the elements you are iterating over. Also, your syntax for `[].push` is wrong.

Comment: @KevinB - Could you explain how to use it to acheive what I am trying to please?

Comment: @MikeChristensen - will do that now

Comment: A HA! This is what I get now:
`join, (an empty string), push <li>Miscellaneous</li>, push <li>Funny Stories</li>, push <li>Animals</li>` So that's all out of order. I shall change it to `$.ajax` and force synch unless anyone has any other suggestions?

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns See my answer for a non-synchronous solution that preserves order (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.promise().done(...)` isn't doing what you think it is. It's simply resolving instantly because there are no animations on the elements you are iterating over. Also, your syntax for `[].push` is wrong.

```
var defArr = $(categories).map(function(index, category_id) {
    return $.post('/modules/blog/add_post_categories', {post_id:result.result, category_id:$(category_id).val()});
}).get();

$.when.apply(null,defArr).done(function() {
    //var categories_names = [];
    //for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    //    categories_names.push(arguments[i][0]);
    //}
    var categories_names = $.map(arguments,function(i,arr) {
        return arr[0];
    });
    var final_cats = categories_names.join("");
    console.info(final_cats);
});
```

Comment: Wow. it would explain why it is all happening out of order as my comment above explained. Thanks for this. I shall try it now - I had no idea that the promise done was confined to animations though?

Comment: Even better, you don't need to manually push the results to the `categories_names` array. The promise of each `$.post` is resolved with an array of the form `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`. Thus, you can retrieve all category names from the promise results in the `done` callback using `$.map(arguments, function(x) { return x[0] });`.

Comment: @HelenDangerBurns `$.promise()` produces a promise for DOM element animations. AJAX requests themselves already implement promises, but you need to make sure that you *keep those promises around* when you want to bind to them! In your original code, there was nothing keeping track of those promises.

Comment: The latest edit makes it populate the array in the correct order

Comment: When you call .promise() on a jQuery collection, it works off of the `"fx"` queue. That's why your original code only tracked animations.

Comment: @KevinB - WOO! It worked perfectly! Thanks! I shall have to look this up and work it all out... thanks for giving me a head start though!

Comment: @KevinB Very nice. I just prefer `map` over manually looping for such small transformations. :-P Small note: your `i` declaration needs a `var`, otherwise it becomes a global.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - thank you! I must do some homework on this I think!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I'm still using `map`, but since i don't know what `categories` is, i left it as-is and used the `$.fn.map` method instead of `$.map`

Comment: @KevinB I was talking about using `$.map` to produce `categories_names` in one line of code (instead of a loop). Nothing ground-breaking though.

Answer (score 0):

```
categories_names.push = result;
```

can you try changing this to

```
categories_names.push(result);
```

because push is a method, not a variable.